# JPanel repaint not working properly

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, repaint

I have a JPanel, class is called `WorldPanel` (look below for code), and I'm using a KeyListener() to move it. It moves, so I don't think it's the `KeyListener` that is at fault. The problem is that when I call `repaint()` on the `JPanel`, it slowly stops repainting a portion of the screen. So (in 1's and 0's with 0 being my image, and 1 being parts not being repainted) the image looks like:

000000000000

`repaint();`

100000000000

`repaint();`

110000000000

etc.

Eventually, the whole panel stops repainting.

WorldPanel.java:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    //This Image is instantiated in the constructor

    //worldImage = ImageIO.read(new File("H:\\Java\\Game\\src\\res\\WorldBase.png"));
    g.drawImage(worldImage, x, y, 6144, 4608, null);
}
public void setX(int x){
    this.x = x;
}
public void setY(int y){
    this.y = y;
}
public int getX(){
    return x;
}
public int getY(){
    return y;
}
```

Implementation of class:

```
worldPanel.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
        Timer timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                worldPanel.repaint();
                timer.stop();
            }
        });
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W && worldPanel.getY() > 0){
                worldPanel.setY(worldPanel.getY() + 1);
                timer.start();
            }
            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A && worldPanel.getX() > 0){
                worldPanel.setX(worldPanel.getX() +1);
                timer.start();
            }
            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S && worldPanel.getY() < 4608){
                worldPanel.setY(worldPanel.getY() - 1);
                timer.start();
            }
            if(arg0.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D && worldPanel.getX() < 6144){
                worldPanel.setX(worldPanel.getX() -1);
                timer.start();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
```

I looked around, and everything I found either said:

- Call repaint on the EDT (tried with using timer)
- Call updateUI() in the `paintComponent` method (apparently the least-liked solution by some people) (tried, didn't work)
- And lastly, Call `super.paintComponent(g)`. Also tried, look in `paintComponent`.

Comment: `Call repaint on the EDT (tried with using timer)` Shouldn't need a Timer here unless you want a delay (or repetitive animation) - the KeyListener methods are being called on the EDT.

Comment: `The problem is that when I call repaint() on the JPanel, it slowly stops repainting a portion of the screen` I don't really understand the problem here. The image is moving across the panel, so their will be positions that are not covered by the image. Do you mean parts of your image are not being painted?

Comment: @copeg I didn't know that.. well, you learn something new every day I guess.

Comment: @copeg I mean parts of my image (from what I can assume) are not being repainted. The old portion of the image is still in it's place, not changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are overriding `JComponent` methods `getX()/setX()/getY()/setY()`. This interferes with calculation of painting area of the panel. Give these methods a different name, ie: `setImageX()/getImageX()`.